# mb_strlen() & strlen() don't return correct values from an Ajax call to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, encoding, utf-8

How can I add a check in the PHP for the length of the $username passed.  The  site is UTF-8 but I believe Javascript is using a different encoding.  You can see in the comments where I tried different things in the PHP and they don't work.

***What I tried and didn't work:***

- Changing Ajax (javascript) to pass variables by UTF-8 and not javascript encoding
- strlen, mb_strlen in the PHP - both return incorrect values

***MORE INFO***

My Ajax sends a username to my PHP, which checks the SQL DB and returns available or not.  I decided to try and do some extra checking in the PHP before checking the DB (like `mb_strlen($username`).  `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` is also set.

I was going to try and send the Ajax request in UTF-8 but didnt see a way to do that.

**is UPPER being used correctly in the MySQL? - for UTF-8 stuff?**

**PHP BELOW *********************

```
// Only checks for the username being valid or not and returns 'taken' or 'available'
require_once('../defines/mainDefines.php'); // Connection variables
require_once('commonMethods.php');
require_once('sessionInit.php');    // start session, check for HTTP redid to HHHTPs

sleep(2);   // Looks cool watching the spinner

$username = $_POST['username'];

//if (mb_strlen($username) < MIN_USERNAME_SIZE) echo 'invalid_too_short';

//if (mb_strlen($username, 'UTF-8') < 10) { echo ('invalid_too_short'); exit; }
//die ('!1!' .  $username . '!2!' . mb_strlen($username) . '!3!' . strlen($username) . '!4!');

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_READER, DB_READER_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or     die(DB_CONNECT_ERROR . DB_HOST .  '--QueryDB--checkName.php');
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);

$query = "SELECT username FROM pcsuser WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER(?)";
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
    die('SEL:mysqli_prepare failed somehow:' . $query . '--QueryDB--checkName.php');
}

if (!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $username)) {
    die('mysqli_stmt_bind_param failed somehow --checkName.php');
}

if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    die('mysqli_stmt_execute failed somehow' . '--checkName.php');
}

mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$num_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row);           
echo ($num_rows >= 1) ? 'taken' : 'available';

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

AJAX CODE BELOW

```
function CheckUsername(sNameToCheck) {
document.getElementById("field_username").className = "validated";
registerRequest = CreateRequest();
if (registerRequest === null)
    alert("Unable to create AJAX request");
else {
  var url= "https://www.perrycs.com/php/checkName.php";
  var requestData = "username=" + escape(sNameToCheck); // data to send
  registerRequest.onreadystatechange = ShowUsernameStatus;
  registerRequest.open("POST", url, true);
  registerRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  registerRequest.send(requestData);
}
}


function ShowUsernameStatus() {
var img_sad = "graphics/signup/smiley-sad006.gif";
var img_smile = "graphics/signup/smiley-happy088.gif";
var img_checking = "graphics/signup/bluespinner.gif";

if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
        var txtUsername = document.getElementById('txt_username');
        var fieldUsername = document.getElementById('field_username');
        var imgUsername = document.getElementById('img_username');
        var error = true;
        var response = request.responseText;

        switch (response) {
            case "available":
                txtUsername.innerHTML = "NAME AVAILABLE!";
                error = false;                  
                break;
            case "taken":
                txtUsername.innerHTML = "NAME TAKEN!";
                break;
            case "invalid_too_short": 
                txtUsername.innerHTML = "TOO SHORT!";
                break;
            default:
                txtUsername.innerHTML = "AJAX ERROR!";
                break;
        } // matches switch

        if (error) {
            imgUsername.src = img_sad;
            fieldUsername.className = 'error';
        } else {
            imgUsername.src = img_smile;
            fieldUsername.className = 'validated';
        }
    } // matches ===200
} // matches ===4
}
```

**TESTING RESULTS**

This is what I get back when I DIE in the PHP and echo out as in the following (before and after making the Ajax change below [adding in UTF-8 to the request]...

***PHP SNIPPIT***

```
die ('!1!' .  $username . '!2!' . mb_strlen($username) . '!3!' . strlen($username) . '!4!');
```

***TEST DATA***

**Username:** David Perry

!1!David Perry!2!11!3!11!4!

**Username:** Ü¦"~÷Û♦

!1!ܦ\"~��%u2666!2!9!3!13!4!

The first one works.  The second one should work but it looks like the encoding is weird (understandable).

7 visible characters for the 2nd one.  mb_strlen shows 9, strlen shows 13.

After reading Joeri Sebrechts solution and link they gave me I looked up Ajax request parameters and someone had the following...

***AJAX SNIPPIT*** (changed from original code)

```
registerRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

(I added in the `charset=UTF-8` from an example I saw on a article).

**UPDATE: Nov 27, 9:11pm EST**

Ok, after much reading I believe I am encoding my JS wrong.  I was using escape... as follows...

```
var requestData = "username=" + escape(sNameToCheck);
```

After looking at this website...

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/

it helped me understand more of what's going on with each function and how they encode and decode.  I should be able to do this...

```
var requestData = "username=" + encodeURIComponent(sNameToCheck);
```

in JS and in PHP I should be able to do this...

```
$username = rawurldecode($_POST['username']);
```

Doing that still gives me 8 characters for my weird example above instead of 7.  It's close, but am I doing something wrong?  If I cursor through the text on the screen it's 7 characters.   Any ideas to help me understand this better?

**FIXED/SOLVED!!!**

Ok, thank you for your tips that lead me in the right direction to make this work.  My changes were as follows.

**In the AJAX** *-- i used to have escape(sNameToCheck); --*

```
var requestData = "username=" + encodeURIComponent(sNameToCheck);
```

**In the PHP** *-- I used to have $username = $_POST['username']; --*

```
$username = rawurldecode($_POST['username']);
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $username = stripslashes($username);
```

I really hate magic_quotes... it's caused me about 50+ hours of frustration over form data in total because I forgot about it.  As long as it works.  I'm happy!

So, now the mb_strlen works and I can easily add this back in...

```
if (mb_strlen($username) < MIN_USERNAME_SIZE) { echo 'invalid_too_short'; exit; }
```

Works great!

Comment: That paragraph... hurts. Monolithic, pedantic, looong. Please edit (at least add some paragraph breaks).

Comment: Well, you have `mb_strlen()` section commented out for whatever reason. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Hi there.   mb_strlen and strlen both give wrong values because I believe it's encoded differently in the Ajax call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is a byte processor, it is not charset-aware. That has a number of tricky consequences.

Strlen() returns the length in bytes, not the length in characters. This is because php's "string" type is actually an array of bytes. Utf8 uses more than one byte per character for the 'special characters'. Therefore strlen() will only give you the right answer for a narrow subset of text (= plain english text).

Mb_strlen() treats the string as actual characters, but assumes it's in the encoding specified via mbstring.internal_encoding, because the string itself is just an array of bytes and does not have metadata specifying its character set. If you are working with utf8 data and set internal_encoding to utf8 it will give you the right answer. If your data is not utf8 it will give you the wrong answer.

Mysql will receive a stream of bytes from php, and will parse it based on the database session's character set, which you set via the SET NAMES directive. Everytime you connect to the database you must inform it what encoding your php strings are in.

The browser receives a stream of bytes from php, and will parse it based on the content-type charset http header, which you control via php.ini default_charset. The ajax call will submit in the same encoding as the page it runs from.

Summarized, you can find advice on the following page on how to ensure all your data is treated as utf8. Follow it and your problem should resolve itself.
http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/

Comment: I forgot some lines of code that might be the problem...   in the initial Ajax call

    registerRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

When I printed what the PHP sees it's a bunch of weird /u2323 stuff.  So, I assume that's the Ajax encoding.  

Is there a way to pass my Ajax as UTF-8?

Comment: I re-edited my post with more code so you can see exactly what I'm doing.Without the check for length it does work (maybe its a fluke its working).It inserts into the DB, tells me if its taken or not.  Works perfectly (or so it seems). I also tried it with weird characters. The problem arose when I tried adding checks to the length.  I also read that article you linked - thank you muchly.  It helps.  I have done everything in it previously except the 'uni' option I read.  I'll have to look that one up more.  (sorry to keep changing my post, don't wanna annoy you when you're trying to help).

Comment: OH... so maybe I'm messing it up by adding in...

registerRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

If Ajax submits the call in the same encoding as the page....   Hmm...

Comment: Ok, I added in some real data to the test.  Can you look that over for me please?   Much appreciated.  Above you will see TESTING DATA... in bold.

Comment: Ok, after a few hours of reading I believe you put me on the correct path to figuring this out.  I'll add some more info to my original question to show you... it still doesnt work 100% but maybe you can tell me why... (please and thank you).

Comment: FIXED IT!   I know why it was showing 8 characters instead of 7...   It was a "bug" I had happen previously...

I HATE MAGIC QUOTES!!!!!    

I will edit my question and show the fixes...

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: thank you for explaining the step by step process of how each transmits data to the other.  That's the kind of info I need.  I'm used to books like "Mapping the C64" (assembly language book from 1984?) that explains EVERYTHING.  Call this function and it does THIS, and THAT, and it leaves the CPU in THIS state.  I hate not knowing what everything does in todays software.  I used to write everything myself.  Using other peoples' functions drives me crazy due to lack of information.  Thanks for filling in some blanks for me!  It helps a lot to understand what really goes on!

Comment: Glad you found the answer while i was sleeping ;) I forgot about magic quotes, because for over 5 years i've been including a sanity check file that checks php.ini for correct settings, and that's one of the checks. Btw, read up on mbstring's function overloading, it can cause weird behavior at times too.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance, you can clean this up:

```
if (request.status == 200) {
    if (request.responseText == "available") {
        document.getElementById("txt_username").innerHTML = "NAME AVAILABLE!";
        document.images['img_username'].src=img_smile;
        document.getElementById("continue").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("field_username").className = 'validated';
    } else if (request.responseText == "taken") {
        document.getElementById("txt_username").innerHTML = "NAME TAKEN!";
        document.images['img_username'].src=img_sad;
        document.getElementById("field_username").className = 'error';
    } else if (request.responseText == "invalid_too_short") {
        document.getElementById("txt_username").innerHTML = "TOO SHORT!";
        document.images['img_username'].src=img_sad;
        document.getElementById("field_username").className = 'error';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("txt_username").innerHTML = "AJAX ERROR!";
                document.images['img_username'].src=img_sad;
        document.getElementById("field_username").className = 'error';
    }
  }
```

to:

```
// I prefer triple equals
// Read more at http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html
if (request.status === 200) {
        // use variables!
        var txtUsername = document.getElementById('txt_username');
        var fieldUsername = document.getElementById('field_username');
        var imgUsername = document.getElementById('img_username');

        var response = request.responseText;

        var error = true;

        // you can do a switch statement here too, if you prefer
        if (response === "available") {
            txtUsername.innerHTML = "NAME AVAILABLE!";

            document.getElementById("continue").disabled = false;

            error = false;

        } else if (response === "taken") {
            txtUsername.innerHTML = "NAME TAKEN!";

        } else if (response === "invalid_too_short") {
            txtUsername.innerHTML = "TOO SHORT!";

        } else {
            txtUsername.innerHTML = "AJAX ERROR!";
        }

        // refactor error actions
        if (error) {
            imgUsername.src = img_sad;
            fieldUsername.className = 'error';
        } else {
            imgUsername.src = img_smile;
            fieldUsername.className = 'validated';
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!   Your method is cleaner.  I'll tidy my code up!   Any way you can help with the strlen portion of it?

Comment: I read the article you linked.  Never thought of it that way!  Thanks for the tip!  I try and practice good programming but when learning - wow... so much to take in!  lol  I've used === before but I didnt know what was in that article.  Thx!!!