# PHP strlen() nor mb_strlen() returning unexpected results

Tags: php, strlen

With PHP, I'm Trying to determine the length (number of characters) in strings such as these:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.1.3.1
1.1.3.2
1.1.4
1.1.5
1.1.6
1.1.7
```

etc.

When the length of these strings are measured with mb_strlen() or strlen(), the results are

```
------------------------------
value   | mb_strlen() | strlen()
------------------------------
1       | 1           | 1
------------------------------
1.1     | 5           | 5
------------------------------
1.1.1   | 9           | 9
------------------------------
1.1.1.1 | 13          | 13
------------------------------
1.1.1.2 | 13          | 13
------------------------------
1.1.1.3 | 13          | 13
------------------------------
```

It appears that it's counting "." as 3 characters? I'm wondering about just doing a small function to compensate for the predictable "miscount", but am wondering why it's counting the "." as 3 characters to begin with.

I have already looked through several places including [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250709/mb-strlen-strlen-dont-return-correct-values-from-an-ajax-call-to-php) and [read the article mentioned,](http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/) adding the suggested conversions to the page:

```
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

What gives?

EDIT:
The strings are imported as part of a csv import.

Here is code:

```
<?
    $f = fopen("s2db.csv", "r");
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {

            $colcount = 0;
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                //lets get the lines into variables first
                //there only five, so just count
                switch ($colcount) {
                    case '0':
                        $item = $cell;
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        $itemtitle = htmlspecialchars($cell);
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $itemsubject = htmlspecialchars($cell);
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        $itemnumber = htmlspecialchars($cell);
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        $itemqty = htmlspecialchars($cell);
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        $itemfilename = htmlspecialchars($cell);
                        break;                    
                }
                $colcount++;
            }
            $itemlen = strlen($item);
            echo "Value = " . $item . " | strlen() Length = " . $itemlen .  "|  mb_strlen() = " . mb_strlen($item) . "</br>";
    }
?>
```

Here are results

```
Value = 1 | strlen() Length = 3| mb_strlen() = 3
Value = 1.1 | strlen() Length = 7| mb_strlen() = 7
Value = 1.1.1 | strlen() Length = 11| mb_strlen() = 11
Value = 1.1.1.1 | strlen() Length = 15| mb_strlen() = 15
Value = 1.1.1.2 | strlen() Length = 15| mb_strlen() = 15
Value = 1.1.1.3 | strlen() Length = 15| mb_strlen() = 15
Value = 1.1.1.3.1 | strlen() Length = 19| mb_strlen() = 19
Value = 1.1.1.3.2 | strlen() Length = 19| mb_strlen() = 19
Value = 1.1.1.3.3 | strlen() Length = 19| mb_strlen() = 19
Value = 1.1.1.4 | strlen() Length = 15| mb_strlen() = 15
```

**SOLUTION:**

I gave @hek2mgl the vote because his hexdump helped me determine that I wasn't crazy and it really was counting the "." as 3, [as shown here](http://pastebin.com/Barz1Y5P#).

Nothing I can do about the import format, so I'm just going to add code to compensate:

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: What char code your dot has? What is the output of `php -r 'echo ord(".");'`

Comment: The code you have suggested doesn't quite work - you haven't quoted the strings, so they're dealt with as numbers, and so they're not valid.  Much be worth correcting that...

Comment: To be clear, the *output* of your code is `strlen(1.1.1.3.3)` but it actually calls those functions with *string* arguments?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue: http://ideone.com/W3dF8t

Comment: @ComFreek: because your inputs are strings, OP's aren't.

Comment: @Glavić `1.1.1` will yield a syntax error, therefore I highly doubted that the code in the question is the code the OP is working with.

Comment: @Glavić even without quotes : http://ideone.com/7lHdEW

Comment: where do the strings come from? ajax?

Comment: Check the csv file encoding

Comment: to be dot or not to be `.·･‧⋅·` [Interpunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct#In_mathematics_and_science)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got:

```
<?php

$str = '1.1.1';
var_dump(mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8'));  // 5
var_dump(strlen($str));              // 5
```

as expected. Seems the `.` in your case isn't the regular dot but a special unicode char. Please show a hexdump of your input data. You can use [Hexdump](https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump) (I wrote the package for such cases):

**Installation**:

```
sudo pear channel-discover www.metashock.de/pear
sudo pear install metashock/Hexdump
```

**Usage:**

```
<?php

require_once 'Hexdump.php';
hexdump('1.1.1');
```

Would be interesting to see what are the real characters behind the scenes.

Comment: First: That's a sweet little package! Here are the results: http://pastebin.com/Barz1Y5P#

Comment: Yeah, that's the output I wanted!! :).. You see that there is a `0` byte before each `.`. Where do you have the strings from?

Comment: I have no control over the csv file that I'm importing, but know that it will be the same every time. is there a way to determin it's encoding so mb_strlen() can read it correctly?

Comment: @Edward That's not a *real* encoding. Never seen this before. Can you show the full csv? (on pastebin?)

Comment: It's bizarre, when I open the file in sublimetext, it looks fine... But, I've copy and pasted to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/DmfxeApK

Comment: @Edward For me it looks fine as well.

Comment: so what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not an answer, but for code formatting reasons.

The following, saved in a UTF-8 file, on my setup...

```
<?php

echo 'mbstring.internal_encoding: '    . ini_get( 'mbstring.internal_encoding' ) . "\r\n";
echo 'mbstring.func_overload: '        . ini_get( 'mbstring.func_overload' ) . "\r\n";
echo 'mbstring.language: '             . ini_get( 'mbstring.language' ) . "\r\n";
echo 'mbstring.strict_detection: '     . ini_get( 'mbstring.strict_detection' ) . "\r\n";
echo 'mbstring.substitute_character: ' . ini_get( 'mbstring.substitute_character' ) . "\r\n";
echo 'mbstring.detect_order: '         . ini_get( 'mbstring.detect_order' ) . "\r\n";
echo 'mbstring.encoding_translation: ' . ini_get( 'mbstring.encoding_translation' ) . "\r\n";
echo "\r\n";

function outputLengths( $sString )  {
    echo( "mb_strlen('$sString', 'utf-8') = " . mb_strlen($sString, 'utf-8')  ."\r\n" );
    echo( "strlen('$sString') = " . strlen($sString)  ."\r\n\r\n" );
}

outputLengths( '1' );
outputLengths( '1.1' );
outputLengths( '1.1.1' );
outputLengths( '1.1.3.1' );
```

Outputs:

```
mbstring.internal_encoding: UTF-8
mbstring.func_overload: 0
mbstring.language: neutral
mbstring.strict_detection: 0
mbstring.substitute_character:
mbstring.detect_order:
mbstring.encoding_translation: 0

mb_strlen('1', 'utf-8') = 1
strlen('1') = 1

mb_strlen('1.1', 'utf-8') = 3
strlen('1.1') = 3

mb_strlen('1.1.1', 'utf-8') = 5
strlen('1.1.1') = 5

mb_strlen('1.1.3.1', 'utf-8') = 7
strlen('1.1.3.1') = 7
```

What do you get?

Comment: Copying and pasting your code into my system gives me the same results as you show.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right lines with @hek2mglm, the test just helps to confirm what that answer states - it's a data issue.  So I'll leave this thread alone.

Answer (score 0):

Where does you variables come from?
Could you please show us the real code (instead of pseudocode)?

I tried to reproduce the described behavior and couldn't. Here's some test I conducted:

```
$strArray = array(
    '.',
    '1',
    '1.1',
    '1.1.1',
    1,
    1.1,
);

for ($i = 0; $i<count($strArray); ++$i) {
    print "{$strArray[$i]} -> strlen: ".strlen($strArray[$i])." <br/>";
    print "{$strArray[$i]} -> mb_strlen: ".mb_strlen($strArray[$i])." <br/>";
    print '<br>';  
}
```

This outputs:

```
. -> strlen: 1 
. -> mb_strlen: 1 

1 -> strlen: 1 
1 -> mb_strlen: 1 

1.1 -> strlen: 3 
1.1 -> mb_strlen: 3 

1.1.1 -> strlen: 5 
1.1.1 -> mb_strlen: 5 

1 -> strlen: 1 
1 -> mb_strlen: 1 

1.1 -> strlen: 3 
1.1 -> mb_strlen: 3
```

as expected