# Why mb_strlen and strlen from post value is incorrect PHP?

Tags: php, strlen

With this code, when I fill `漢字` into an input element with type `text` and name `text` and press submit button, its shows `mb_strlen : 16` and `strlen : 16`

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_POST['text']);
    //$string = "漢字";

    echo $string."<BR>";
    echo "mb_strlen : ".mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8')."<BR>";
    echo "strlen : ".strlen($string)."<BR>";

    if(strlen($string) != mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8'))
    { 
        echo "Please enter English words only:(";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "OK, English Detected!";
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" id="button-blue" style=" float: none; ">
</form>
```

But when use this code, it's will show `mb_strlen : 2` and `strlen : 6`

I want to know , why the value from above code is incorrect and how to apply?

```
<?php
    $string = "漢字";

    echo $string."<BR>";
    echo "mb_strlen : ".mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8')."<BR>";
    echo "strlen : ".strlen($string)."<BR>";

    if(strlen($string) != mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8'))
    { 
        echo "Please enter English words only:(";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "OK, English Detected!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Only tip i have: In the second example the PHP-File Encoding plays a role to, because you write the `"漢字"` directly into the file.

Comment: And read here the marked answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250709/mb-strlen-strlen-dont-return-correct-values-from-an-ajax-call-to-php

Comment: Sounds like the data sent by your client is _not_ treated properly as unicode on the server.

Comment: Using `strlen` for this is a bad idea. There are PHP functions built-in that check encoding and check inclusion of certain characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely some gotchas with this answer—which will require later revision—but instead of using `strlen` we can use Regex to check if the input string has non-Latin characters.

Code:

```
$string = '漢字';
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/^[^\p{Latin}]+$/u';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 漢字
)
```

If I tested with `This is a Latin string jasDLFKL@##$&()@!!!` I get an empty array back. I don't believe this is a foolproof solution, but more of a good first step.

Please note that the definition of the Latin character range for Regex is U+0000–U+007F. This [Regex Tutorial Page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) goes into detail about Unicode. Also note that my pattern has a `u` flag, for Unicode. That will be necessary to include.